# DateFormatter gives different dates for iOS 11 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

## Problem

Dates displayed on iOS Simulator 10.3.1 are (for me) one hour behind the same dates displayed on iOS Simulator 11.2 and an iPhone 6 Plus (real device) with iOS 11.2.

## Wanted result

All dates should display the date `4 Jan 2018 14:32` with respect to the dates under **Results**.

## Code

I have managed to reproduce the bug with the following code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
label.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

## Results

These are the dates I see on the different devices (Norwegian dates):

- iPhone 6 Plus (real device) w/ iOS 11.2: `4 Jan 2018 14:32`
- iPhone 5S (simulator) w/ iOS 11.2: `4 Jan 2018 14:32`
- iPhone 5S (simulator) w/ iOS 10.3.1: `4 Jan 2018 13:32`

Comment: Please read this: [IOS changes localized date](https://jaanus.com/ios-11-changes-localized-date-handling)

Comment: Do you have any ideas for the fix? I have already localized my application to Norwegian, so any solutions that entails adding an empty `Strings.strings` file won't be relevant for me.

Comment: Have you tried setting `locale` and `timeZone` of `dateFormatter`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried setting those attributes a bunch of ways with no luck. Will try the second possible solution in the answer posted. Thanks!

Comment: Facing the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646888/dateformatter-gives-different-dates-for-ios-11-converted-to-utc-and-ios-10-no, any solution you got?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Set local):

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
```

Or this (Set System):

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.system
```

Comment: I have tried the first possible solution, but not the second, but I'll have to come back to you tomorrow or the day after – I'll have to try it on a real device running iOS 10 before I can say for sure that it worked. But thanks for your help!

Comment: I see that the dates in my application are one hour behind, but so is the system clock in the Simulator. So the date in the application is correct in regards to the clock of the Simulator. So is it working correctly, then? I have tried to change the system language and region in the Simulator, but the clock is still one hour behind.

Comment: If the system clock in the simulator has a one hour behind then is it working. If you want to change the simulator's clock you need change the clock of your mac (simulator's clock = system's clock)

Comment: The weird thing is that the clock is correct on iOS 11. But in [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80172) Apple forum post several people say that they get the wrong date on iOS 10, but correct on iOS 11, so it's not just me, it seems.