# DateFormatter gives different dates for iOS 11 (converted to UTC) and iOS 10 (not converted to UTC)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Method to convert time string to date object:

```
class func StringToDate(format: String, date: String) -> Date{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.date(from: date)!
    }
```

Format: **hh:mm a**

time string: **10:00 AM**

Result:

String Time: 10:00 AM, Object Time: 2000-01-01 10:00:00 +0000 **//ios 10**

String Time: 10:00 AM, Object Time: 2000-01-01 04:30:00 +0000 **//ios 11**

For iOS v11 result is fine but for iOS v10 its wrong, I want result in UTC format.

**I have tried:**

```
1. formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
2. formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
3. formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.system
```

Comment: Try this one if further required it's working https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477989/10150796

Answer (score 1):

Please add this(it may be happening because your system is picking current timezone)-

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: “UTC”)
```

Comment: Please tell me the time zone of the date parameter in -
'class func StringToDate(format: String, date: String) -> Date{'

Comment: date parameter is of string type, its not a Date object, here I'm converting string date to date object.